# SQL - The column was specified multiple times

Tags: sql, database

I am getting the following error when trying to run this query in SQL:

```
SELECT *
                            FROM [Submissions] AS [s]
                            INNER JOIN [SubmissionHistories] AS [s0] ON [s].[Id] = [s0].[SubmissionId]
                            INNER JOIN
                            ( SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
                                FROM OHis
                                ORDER BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ApplicationId ORDER BY OwnerChangeDate DESC)
                            ) AS [oh] ON [oh].[ApplicationId] = [s].ApplicationId
                            INNER JOIN 
                            ( SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
                                FROM AHis
                                ORDER BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ApplicationId ORDER BY AuthorizedSubmitterChangeDate DESC)
                            ) AS [ash] ON [ash].[ApplicationId] = [s].ApplicationId
```

The column 'ApplicationId' was specified multiple times for 'Submissions'. What am I missing?

Comment: Select the actual columns you need, don't use `select *`

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS as SQL varies in dialects.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that a column called `ApplicationId` appears in more than one table.  Because you are doing a blanket `SELECT *`, your SQL engine can't deal with this.  The corrective action would be to prefix `ApplicationId` with an alias scoping it to a particular table.  For example, assuming that `Submissions` and `SubmissionHistories` have an `ApplicationId` column, you could use:

```sql
SELECT s.ApplicationId AS sAId, s0.ApplicationId AS s0AId, -- other columns here
FROM ...
```

Note that, because of problems like the one you are seeing, it is *always* preferable to explicitly list out all columns you select.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the column name with the table alias created in your join statement.

```
A.Wine_ID,
A.Grape_Name,
A.Grape,
B.Grape, 
B.Grape_Vineyard_Location
FROM WINE_TABLE A
JOIN GRAPE_VINEYARD_TABLE B
ON A.Wine_ID=B.Wine_ID
```

The prefix (A, B) before the 'Grape' column in my select statement allowed me to pull in the Grape column from both the WINE_TABLE A and GRAPE_VINEYARD_TABLE B.